# Did God see or hear the afflictions of the Israelites in Exodus 2 & 3?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 2:23-25 (NASB)

> [23]Now it came about in the course of those many days that the king of Egypt died. And the sons of Israel sighed because of the bondage, and they cried out; and their cry for help because of their bondage rose up to God.
>   [24]So God ***heard*** their groaning; and God remembered His covenant with Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.
>   [25]God ***saw*** the sons of Israel, and God took notice of them

Exodus 3:7 (NASB)

> [7]The Lord said, "I have surely ***seen*** the affliction of My people who are in Egypt, and have given heed to ***their cry*** because of their taskmasters, for I am aware of their sufferings.

Exodus 3:9 (NASB)

> [9]Now, behold, ***the cry*** of the sons of Israel has come to Me; furthermore, I have ***seen*** the oppression with which the Egyptians are oppressing them.

Exodus 3:16 (KJV)

> Go, and gather the elders of Israel together, and say unto them, The Lord God of your fathers, the God of Abraham, of Isaac, and of Jacob, appeared unto me, saying, I have surely visited you, and ***seen*** that which is done to you in Egypt:

Are the two words hearing & seeing being used interchangeable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The "sense words" *seeing* and *hearing* are somewhat interchangeable in the passages you cite from Exodus.

Throughout the Judeo-Christian Scriptures, these anthropomorphic terms are used quite frequently. See 2 Kings 19:16; 1 Chronicles 17:17; 2 Chronicles 16:9; Psalm 18:24; Proverbs 5:21: 15:3; Isaiah 37:17 (cf. Isaiah 6:5 and 11:3!).

We know that YHWH does not literally have eyes or ears, but being omniscient and omnipresent He has no difficulty knowing what his image bearers are saying, doing, and even thinking!

One of the reasons why the prophet of whom Isaiah speaks in Chapters 6 and 11 will not judge by what he sees and hears is because he already knows what is going on in the hearts of those he judges. As the writer to the Hebrews expresses this thought:

> For the word of God is living and active and sharper than any two-edged sword, and piercing as far as the division of soul and spirit, of both joints and marrow, and able to judge the thoughts and intentions of the heart. And there is no creature hidden from His sight, but all things are open and laid bare to the eyes of Him with whom we have to do (4:12-13 NASB).